# List all files à la *.* (star-dot-star) in Windows using Nautilus on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: nautilus

Is there a way to list all files in Nautilus on Ubuntu 18.04 using a query like "star dot star" in Windows?

I've checked other questions like this on Ask Ubuntu and they all lead me down rabbit holes which end up nowhere (e.g. use the edit menu in Nautilus...err...what edit menu?)

Comment: You could do this on the command line, e.g. `ls *.*` or `find -name '*.*'`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short answer: no.

Current versions of nautilus feature "Search". The search facility does not, however, support wildcards. As such, it is not possible to list all files in the current folder and in subfolders that match a wildcard pattern.

Nautilus supports wildcards in its file selection feature. For example, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd> followed by <kbd>`*`</kbd><kbd>`.`</kbd><kbd>`*`</kbd> and <kbd>Enter</kbd> will select all files in the current folder containing a dot in their name.

Comment: `*.*`means all files or directories with a dot in it's name, it will also be evaluated to `.` and `..`. As `*` could also be nothing it is not sure that found files have an extension.

Comment: @mook765 you are of course right. I corrected this in the post.

Comment: If you use kfind, you can put a * in the search field and that will find all files in the current and recursive directories.